# erlang max function logic

Tags: function, erlang, max

I have a maximum function. If I use this like: "module:max(6,6)." the result will be 6.
Why not "X = Y. There is no maximum." ?

```
max(X,Y) when X > Y -> X;
max(X,Y) when X < Y -> Y;
max(X,Y) -> io:fwrite("X = Y. There is no maximum.\n").
```

Comment: I am running the same code as you and it works as you expect

Comment: your code is correct, although I will never use it in my projects ... It introduce a name comflict with the standard erlang max/2 function, but it is solved if you call module:max/2. You can try to rename the function to mymax in order to get some clue about the issue you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

As I said your code should work since it works for me.

But try this one

```
max(X,X) -> io:fwrite("X = Y. There is no maximum.\n");
max(X,Y) when X > Y -> X;
max(X,Y) -> Y.
```

[image]

Comment: module:max(8,8). gives me 8 back again :O

Comment: This is so weird! it is working completely fine for me. is it possible that somehow you are treating the data as float?

Comment: no way :/ i really don't know. i will ask my erlang teacher tomorrow

Comment: I added a screenshot as well. if you find the reason please post here so we can report this bug. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A function must return something. And better without any side effects. How do you understand that inputs are equal in your case? Especially if it's called like 'max(ok, ok)' or 'max(ok, 0)'.

Erlang max function definition just mimics mathematical one, it's the same in all sensible programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

Are you actually using module:max/2 ?

It looks like you're using erlang:max/2.